# nz-select dropdown doesn't connect itself in nz-modal

Tags: angular, ng-zorro-antd

When using nz-select in a nz-modal that content is scrollable, you see the dropdown is not connected to itself after page scroll.

[expect display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyT5q.png)

[error dispaly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqtmT.png)

Here is an example to reproduce the problem [StackBiltz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nht15b?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

Comment: Already post stackBilz link to reproduce the problem. What else can i do?

Comment: Did you find the solution ? I think it's a cdkScrollable to add somewhere but, in my code, I can't find where...

Answer (score 0):

I resolved that with a directive

```
import { ChangeDetectorRef, Directive, Inject, OnDestroy, OnInit, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { NzSelectComponent } from 'ng-zorro-antd/select';

@Directive({
  selector: '[aysrCloseSelectOnScroll]'
})
export class CloseSelectOnScrollDirective implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function
  listenerFn = () => {};
  constructor(
    private el: NzSelectComponent,
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document,
    private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const antModalWrap: HTMLCollectionOf<Element> = this.document.body.getElementsByClassName('ant-modal-wrap');

    this.listenerFn = this.renderer.listen(antModalWrap.item(0), 'scroll', (event) => {
      this.el.nzOpen = false;
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.listenerFn();
  }
}
```

and you can use it

```
 <nz-select aysrCloseSelectOnScroll formControlName="documentation">
              <nz-option [nzValue]="item.id" [nzLabel]="item.label" *ngFor="let item of documentation"></nz-option>
            </nz-select>
          </nz-form-control>
```